# How do i add html element from javascript

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4, innerhtml

I was trying to create a chip when a checkbox  is checked by adding an eventlistener function to the checkbox but it is not happening . I think the element is not being inserted to the html .
Here is the code

```
let ChoosenFiltercontainer = document.getElementById('ChoosenFiltercontainer')
let FilterDropdownsElems = document.querySelector('.FilterDropdowns');
let FilterDropdownsElem = FilterDropdownsElems.querySelectorAll('[type=checkbox]');
let customid = "";
for (let i = 0; i < FilterDropdownsElem.length; i++) {
  customid = customid + FilterDropdownsElem[i].id + i;
  FilterDropdownsElem[i].addEventListener('click', function(customid) {
    ChoosenFiltercontainer.innerHTML += `<div class="col-md-auto " id=${customid}  style="display:none;" >
          <div class="chip chip-outline btn-outline-dark rounded-pill" data-mdb-ripple-color="dark">
            ${FilterDropdownsElem[i].id} <i class="close fas fa-times" style="font-size: small;"></i>
          </div>
        </div>`;
    if (FilterDropdownsElem[i].checked == true) {
      document.getElementById('customid').style.display = "block";
    } else {
      document.getElementById('customid').style.display = "none";
    }
  }.bind(this, customid))
}
```

I think that i am not using the innerHTML property correctly

Comment: Please fix the indentation of your code.

Comment: And also please add the relevant HTML and CSS to the question so we can create a working example to make debugging more clear

Comment: Also what is the need for `}.bind(this,customid)` here?

Comment: *"it is not happening"*: what exactly isn't? Is the `for` loop not entered? Is the event handler not attached? Is the event handler not executing? Is the HTML not altered? What have you debugged? Please provide the code necessary to reproduce the issue (which needs the relevant HTML)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I always suggest delegation so I will refactor instead of debugging your code which has some strange statements, like your .bind

Here is a version that delegates from the filterDropdown container and the ChoosenFiltercontainer

I added the checkbox ID to the close as a data attribute so we can uncheck the filter if we close it

```js
const ChoosenFiltercontainer = document.getElementById('ChoosenFiltercontainer');
document.querySelector('.FilterDropdowns').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  const tgt = e.target;

  if (!tgt.matches("input[type=checkbox]")) return;
  let elementId = `${tgt.id}_container`; // Create a unique ID for the container
  let filterElement = document.getElementById(elementId);
  if (!filterElement) {
    console.log('creating div');
    ChoosenFiltercontainer.innerHTML += `<div class="col-md-auto filter" id="${elementId}" style="display: none;"><div class="chip chip-outline btn-outline-dark rounded-pill" data-mdb-ripple-color="dark">${tgt.id} <i data-id="${tgt.id}" class="close fas fa-times" style="font-size: small;"></i></div></div>`;
    filterElement = ChoosenFiltercontainer.lastChild;
  }
  filterElement.style.display = tgt.checked ? 'block' : 'none';
});
ChoosenFiltercontainer.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  const tgt = e.target;
  if (tgt.matches('i.close')) {
    const filterId = tgt.dataset.id;
    document.getElementById(filterId).checked = false;
    tgt.closest('div.filter').style.display = 'none';
  }  
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.2/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-z3gLpd7yknf1YoNbCzqRKc4qyor8gaKU1qmn+CShxbuBusANI9QpRohGBreCFkKxLhei6S9CQXFEbbKuqLg0DA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
/>

<div id="ChoosenFiltercontainer">
  <!-- Selected filters will be displayed here -->
</div>

<div class="FilterDropdowns">
  <!-- Example checkboxes -->
  <label><input type="checkbox" id="filter1">Filter 1</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" id="filter2">Filter 2</label>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there might be an issue with how you're trying to set the display property based on the checkbox state. Also, there is an issue with the way you're trying to set the ID of the dynamically created div.
Try this:

Use `event.target` to get the clicked checkbox element inside the event handler.

Remove the unnecessary check for checkbox state `(if (FilterDropdownsElem[i].checked == true))` because it's redundant.

Use `div.remove()` to remove the dynamically created div when the corresponding checkbox is unchecked.

```
let ChoosenFiltercontainer = document.getElementById('ChoosenFiltercontainer');
let FilterDropdownsElems = document.querySelector('.FilterDropdowns');
let FilterDropdownsElem = FilterDropdownsElems.querySelectorAll('[type=checkbox]');
let customid = "";

for (let i = 0; i < FilterDropdownsElem.length; i++) {
    customid = FilterDropdownsElem[i].id + i; // Use a simpler customid
    
    FilterDropdownsElem[i].addEventListener('click', function (event) {
        let checkbox = event.target;
        let divId = checkbox.id + i;
        let div = document.getElementById(divId);

        if (checkbox.checked) {
            // If the checkbox is checked, create the div if it doesn't exist
            if (!div) {
                ChoosenFiltercontainer.innerHTML += `<div class="col-md-auto" id="${divId}">
                    <div class="chip chip-outline btn-outline-dark rounded-pill" data-mdb-ripple-color="dark">
                        ${checkbox.id} <i class="close fas fa-times" style="font-size: small;"></i>
                    </div>
                </div>`;
            }
        } else {
            // If the checkbox is unchecked, remove the corresponding div
            if (div) {
                div.remove();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about the rest of your code since you haven't provided the html and CSS files.
Anyways reading your code, and using customId as a string rather than as a variable could be the problem, if everything else is fine.

```
document.getElementById('customid').style.display = "block";
```

try changing this to

```
document.getElementById(customid).style.display = "block";
```

do the same for the display = "none" case